# Beginner polynomial program in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm looking for some assistance on an exercise for my C++ programming class. Unfortunately, I was rather ill this week and unable to attend class, meaning I have only been able to use the textbook as a resource, so I'm pretty lost when it comes to writing this program. Therefore, I figured I'd turn to the real pros here for assistance. I realize this is broad, but any help and/or tips would be appreciated. Here are the instructions we were given:

> This assignment deals with representing and manipulating polynomials using simple arrays. A
>   polynomial, such as anxn + an-1xn-1 + … + a0, will be implemented as an array of coefficients, with >coefficient ai being stored in location i of the array. The coefficients are floating point values
>   (potentially negative), so we will use an array of type double. The array will be of size *MAXPOLY*
>   (a constant variable set to 50) and so we will be limited to holding polynomials with maximum
>   degree of *MAXPOLY* – 1 (or 49).
>   The file **Poly.h** describes all the functions provided by the class. 
>   You are to implement the following set of functions:
>    - Default constructor to initialize a polynomial to the zero
>      polynomial
>    - *setCoeff* to set a specific coefficient in the polynomial
>    - *retrieveCoeff* to get a specific coefficient from the polynomial
>    - *incrementCoeff* to add a value to a specific coefficient in the polynomial
>    - *degree* which determines the degree of the polynomial
>    - *numOfTerms* which determines the number of terms in the polynomial (i.e., how many array elements are nonzero)
>    - *evaluate* which evaluates the polynomial for a given value of X
>    - *add* which adds one polynomial to another, changing the polynomial added to
>    - *derivative* which computes the derivative of a polynomial
>    - *equals* which determines the equality of two polynomials
>
> Several functions are provided for you: (1) a *toString* function will be provided to you so that >all our polynomials will be displayed identically, (2) the insertion operator is defined so we can >easily print a polynomial, and (3) the equality, inequality, and addition operators are provided >and are simply defined in terms of your equals and add functions. You should not change any of the provided functions.
>
> You will be supplied two starter files, **Poly.cpp** and **Poly.h**. The class declaration
>   file Poly.h contains a complete specification of a class named Poly. Your task will be to implement >all the specified functions in the class definition file Poly.cpp (with the exception of the few >functions which have been provided for you.). You have also been provided with an initial test >program PolyTest.cpp. You should add code to the PolyTest.cpp file to fully test your Poly class(copy code from the PolyTest.cpp file you created for Project #1-Pre).

We were, indeed, supplied those files. The **Poly.h** file looks like this:

```
#define POLY_H
#ifndef POLY_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const size_t MAXPOLY = 50;    

class Poly
{

private:
    // Data members   [implementation of ADT's data object]

    // array for holding the coefficients of the poly
    double coeff[MAXPOLY];               
public:

    // Default Class constructor: initializes a polynomial to the constant 0
    // note: all array elements of coeff[] must be set to 0.0  
    Poly ();

    // degree: finds the degree of a polynomial (the highest power with a non-zero coefficient)
    size_t degree () const;

    // setCoeff: sets a term, value*x^i, in a polynomial
        // Throws <std::out_of_range> if index i does not meet the precondition.
    void setCoeff (double value, size_t i);

    // retrieveCoeff: finds the coefficient of the x^i term in poly
    // Throws <std::out_of_range> if index i does not meet the precondition.
    double retrieveCoeff (size_t i) const;

    // incrementCoeff: changes a term, value*x^i, in a polynomial
    // Throws <std::out_of_range> if index i does not meet the precondition.
    void incrementCoeff(double value, size_t i);

    // toString: produce a string representation of a Poly object
    // note: This function has been provided for you -- DO NOT CHANGE IT!
    string toString() const;

    // numOfTerms: returns the number of terms in the polynomial.
    size_t numOfTerms () const;

    // evaluate: evaluate a polynomial for a specified value of X
    double evaluate (double x) const;

    // add: add one polynomial to another
    void add (const Poly& aPoly);

    // addition operator: add two polynomials together and return a new polynomial that is the result
    // note: This function has been provided for you -- DO NOT CHANGE IT!
    Poly operator+ (const Poly& rhs) const;

    // equals: determine if two polynomials are equal
    bool equals (const Poly& aPoly) const;

    // Equality/inequality operators
    // note: These functions have been provided for you -- DO NOT CHANGE IT!
    bool operator== (const Poly& rhs) const;
    bool operator!= (const Poly& rhs) const;

    // derivative: compute the derivative of a polynomial
    void derivative ();

    // insertion operator for output
    // note: This function has been provided for you -- DO NOT CHANGE IT!
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Poly &p);
};  

#endif
```

The **Poly.cpp** file looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cmath>
#include "Poly.h"
using namespace std;


// Class constructor
Poly::Poly ()
{
    //ADD YOUR CODE HERE
}

// degree
size_t Poly::degree() const
{
    //ADD YOUR CODE HERE
}

// setCoeff
void Poly::setCoeff (double value, size_t i)
{
    // ADD YOUR CODE HERE
}

// retrieveCoeff
double Poly::retrieveCoeff (size_t i) const
{
    return 0;    // REPLACE WITH YOUR CODE
}

// incrementCoeff
void Poly::incrementCoeff(double value, size_t i)
{
    // ADD YOUR CODE HERE
}

// toString
string Poly::toString() const
{
    ostringstream result;
    bool printedSomething = false;
    for (int i=(int)degree(); i>=0; i--) 
    {
          double c = retrieveCoeff(i);
          if (c != 0.0) 
      {
          printedSomething = true;
          if (i == 0) 
      {
              result.setf(ios::showpos);
              result << " " << c;
              result.unsetf(ios::showpos);
          }
          else 
      {
              result.setf(ios::showpos);
              result << " " << c;
              result.unsetf(ios::showpos);
              result << "*X^" << i;
          }
          }
      }
    if (!printedSomething) 
    {
        result.setf(ios::showpos);
        result << " " << 0;
        result.unsetf(ios::showpos);
    }
    return result.str();
}


// numOfTerms
size_t Poly::numOfTerms () const
{
    return 0;   // REPLACE WITH YOUR CODE
}

// evaluate
double Poly::evaluate (double x) const
{
    return 0;   // REPLACE WITH YOUR CODE
}

// add
void Poly::add (const Poly& aPoly)
{
    // ADD YOUR CODE HERE
}

// addition operator
Poly Poly::operator+ (const Poly& rhs) const
{
    Poly result;
    result.add(*this);
    result.add(rhs);
    return result;
}

// equals
bool Poly::equals (const Poly& aPoly) const
{
    return false;   // REPLACE WITH YOUR CODE
}

// Equality/inequality operators
bool Poly::operator== (const Poly& rhs) const
{
    return equals(rhs);
}

bool Poly::operator!= (const Poly& rhs) const
{
    return !equals(rhs);
}

// derivative
void Poly::derivative ()
{
    // ADD YOUR CODE HERE
}

// Friend operator for printing a Poly object.
ostream & operator << (ostream &out, const Poly& p)
{
    out << p.toString();
    return out;
}

#endif
```

Although I have a basic understanding of C++, this is only the second week of classes (apparently a bad one to miss), so I am still in the learning stages. Any help, even if it is just a place to start, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Note:** I am compiling in Microsoft Visual Studio if that is of any help

Comment: It seems very strange, that you are provided with this `Poly.h` as it was pointed out by the answer, it is not really correct.

Comment: @sukhmel I agree, it is rather strange and I have since emailed the professor about the error. Though he has yet to write back, I assume it must have been a mistake on his part.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things with your posted code.

1. You need to switch the following lines in `Poly.h`:

   ```
   #define POLY_H
   #ifndef POLY_H
   ```

   Otherwise, nothing from the file gets included.
2. It's a bad practice to use

   ```
   using namespace std;
   ```

   in a .h file. Use explicit type names, such as `std::string` and `std::ostream`.

Coming to your main obstacle, you have to figure out how to implement the functions in `Poly.cpp`. You can use a test driven approach to flesh out the contents of the file.

Let's say you have a file named `TestPoly.cpp`. The file contains the `main` function and drives testing of the implementation of `Poly`.

You can start with:

```
void testSetCoeff();

int main()
{
   testSetCoeff();
   return 0;
}
```

How would you implement `testSetCoeff`?

Here's something to start off:

```
void testSetCoeff()
{
   std::cout << "Testing setCoeff()/retrieveCoeff(): ";

   // Construct an instance of Poly.
   Poly p;

   // Set the 0-the coefficient.       
   p.setCoeff(1.0, 0);

   // Retrieve the same coefficient.
   double c = p.retrieveCoeff(0);

   // Make sure that we get the same value.
   if ( almostEqual(c, 1.0) )
   {
      std::cout << "SUCCESS\n";
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "FAILURE\n";
   }
}
```

The strategy followed in the function:

1. Set some data on an object.
2. Retrieve the data from the same object.
3. Make sure that you get back a value that makes sense. Add an appropriate test for it.

In the function above, I chose to use

```
   if ( almostEqual(c, 1.0) )
```

instead of

```
   if ( c == 1.0 )
```

to make sure that we are able to deal with the inexact nature of floating point representations.

The implementation of `almostEqual` is something like:

```
bool almostEqual(double x, double y)
{
   static double const tolerance = 1.0E-6;
   return (fabs(x-y) < tolerance);
}
```

Putting these all together, the content of the starter version of `TestPoly.cc` will be:

```
#include "Poly.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

bool almostEqual(double x, double y);
void testSetCoeff();

int main()
{
   testSetCoeff();
   return 0;
}

bool almostEqual(double x, double y)
{
   static double const tolerance = 1.0E-6;
   return (fabs(x-y) < tolerance);
}

void testSetCoeff()
{
   std::cout << "Testing setCoeff()/retrieveCoeff(): ";

   // Construct an instance of Poly.
   Poly p;

   // Set the 0-the coefficient.       
   p.setCoeff(1.0, 0);

   // Retrieve the same coefficient.
   double c = p.retrieveCoeff(0);

   // Make sure that we get the same value.
   if ( almostEqual(c, 1.0) )
   {
      std::cout << "SUCCESS\n";
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "FAILURE\n";
   }
}
```

With the current state of `Poly.cpp`, you will get `FAILURE` status. Now you can go to `Poly.cpp` and figure out how to change the implementations of `setCoeff` and `retrieveCoeff` to make that test pass.

```
// setCoeff
void Poly::setCoeff (double value, size_t i)
{
   coeff[i] = value;
}

// retrieveCoeff
double Poly::retrieveCoeff (size_t i) const
{
   return coeff[i];
}
```

Then, you can start adding other tests. They will most likely fail first. Then you implement the necessary functions until those tests pass.

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

The coefficients can be initialized to `0` in the constructor using [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset).

```
Poly::Poly ()
{
   memset(coeff, 0, sizeof(coeff));
}
```

**P.S.:** Remember to #include `cstring` to use `memset`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, that was really helpful and I am now feeling that I am off to a decent start. I am, however, struggling a bit with the default constructor for this problem and was hoping you might be able to offer similar insight on that. The instructions state that the class constructor must initialize a polynomial (class object) to a degree-0 polynomial of 0. I am slightly confused as to whether, on this occasion, I should first initialize the entire array for 0-MAXPOLY and then the poly at 0, or one or the other. Any advice?